# What's the point of defining $\sigma(A)\vee\sigma(B)$ when $\sigma(A)\vee\sigma(B)=\sigma(A,B):=\sigma(A\cup B)$?

Tags: probability-theory

This question is related to [Joining sigma algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183233/joining-sigma-algebras).

I'm new to the probability theory and wonder why we introduce the notation $\sigma(A)\vee\sigma(B)$, if it's simply $\sigma(A,B)$. Why??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because we don't always have to view sigma algebras as being generated by some collection (i.e. $\sigma(A)$) -- if $F$ and $G$ are sigma algebra then $F \lor G = \sigma(F \cup G)$, but $F \lor G$ is shorter to write.

Also, it makes sense to consider $\lor$ as a separate important operation on sigma algebras, even if it has a simple definition $\sigma(F \cup G)$.